# Python good for prototyping and not for large scale deployment?

Tags: python

I am new to python and one thing I read is python is good for making fast prototype of your product because of its extensive library support. But it is not good(used) for large scale deployment?

Is it true? your comments on this.

I have not seen a place (domain) where it is heavily used although its a beautiful language with big fan following (like php for server scripting, JS for client side; c c++ for systems etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google uses it, and I think this is a good example for large-scale deployment. It is not very fast, indeed, but it has **awesome** C/C++ integration support for the bottlenecks.

Comment: I wouldn't say that any of Google's uses of Python are "large-scale" - they mostly use Python for little glue scripts and such. I think their last remaining user-visible use of Python is support.py. I used to work at Google, and we did try to use Python for a number of large-scale things, but they always ended up collapsing under their own weight. Any sufficiently complex system eventually needs refactoring, and that's really hard without the ability to statically analyze your code. It ends up being easier to just rewrite, and we'd usually switch to something with static type checking.

Comment: I should add that I love Python. When I code for fun, it's the language I use most of the time. I think there is certainly a lot of truth to the idea that it isn't cut out for really large systems, however. That's okay. A really good hammer doesn't have to be good at cutting 2x4's.

Comment: @Laurence Gonsalves : No language is cut out for large systems. Any large system uses multitude of solutions for varying requirements.

Comment: @pyfunc Yes, really large systems are often built using a variety of tools. The fact remains that even when talking about large components that are written in a single language, the ones I've seen that were written in Python usually ended up being rewritten in another language (often Java) because the Python code just became impossible to maintain. My feeling is that Python is optimized for systems that are small enough that a single person fully grok 100% of the code. Once it doesn't all fit in one brain you need static analysis, and Python is just too dynamic for that to be practical.

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves A large potion of the Youtube code base is written in Python. This is "large-scale."

Answer (score 2):

The example I would give would be CCP Games who use Python for almost all code, iirc. They run eve online, a MMORPG with the record for the max amount of users online in one persistent universe (over 50 thousand yesterday afternoon for instance). So I would say that is a fairly large scale deployment, in my humble opinion.