# What are the Uses of Python?

Tags: python, programming-languages, python-3.x, software-design

*I'm new here, so forgive me if I wrote something wrong here...*
For which-all fields can Python be used for and to which extent? 
Can Python be used to make softwares(with GUI, for different platforms ) and web apps?

**UPDATE*- I want to make simple software ( for my works and enjoyment and a little of web dev. )**

I'm asking this question as I'm confused between Ruby, ASP, PHP and Python for Web Development and want to know if Python should be better to learn before C++ ( although I can understand C++ learning ) 
* Which are good IDEs and web frameworks for Python?
Do help me and refer a few free ebooks and web-pages to learn. And which one is better?2.xx or 3.xx?

Thanks in advance!
John

Comment: This question has a scope like the "meaning of life" :-P

Comment: Try this on programmers and you might get a better response.

Comment: Nix is right. Additionally, when asking on *programmers*, provide some more details what your constraints are (because every language you named is suited for web development).

Comment: I am afraid that programmers would not like this either as it is too open.

Comment: Programmers: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's [used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381239/python-good-for-prototyping-and-not-for-large-scale-deployment) for all sorts of things. There are lots of [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896621/books-to-learn-php-python/1896626#1896626) about books. [2 vs 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442352/python-2-vs-python-3-and-tutorial) searching before asking can get you good results.

Answer (score 2):

This type of question is a bit of a hornets nest since your mileage may vary and it is largely dependent on opinion. But I'll show a few usecases.

You can use Python for near all. The [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) of Python is a good start.

You could start out by learning Python 3.x but be advised that near all real-world stuff is still in Python 2. Read this [article](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3) to learn more about what to pick.

Python is used for web development through a lot of frameworks like [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), [Pylons](http://pylonsproject.org/), [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/). You can use Python to make GUIs with [Qt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro), [GTK](http://www.pygtk.org/), Tk and assorted others.

If you want to start web developing I suggest to read the tutorial first and then go with Django as your general introduction.

As for IDEs, whatever floats your boat, you can go small from vim to huge with pydev.

Some examples of bigger applications and companies using Python: YouTube, Civilization (game series), Google, Dropbox. A more comprehensive list is found on the [Python wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/OrganizationsUsingPython).

Comment: and for software development for small scale apps?

Comment: A million smaller opensource projects and small scale websites are written in Python. From simple command line applications to full scale networking libraries. From homegrown websites to multi-million hit websites :-) Just search for a few on Bitbucket or Github to see more!

Comment: @John IMO it's better for small scale apps than for big scale apps since the disadvantages of dynamic typing become more pronounced in big programs. But language is mainly a matter of preference.